# How to send generated view to another Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hi everybody  i've faced with one a problem 
i 've got Class1 where i call request and received data(JSON)
than i send as parameter this data to Class 2 and parsing it and generate view(i'm putting programmly labels, textfields, buttons etc) after all this operation i've to send this view to another Class3
How i should organize such way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do it upon initialization of Class3:

```
Class3 * pClass3= [[Class3 alloc] initWithView:pClass2View];
```

or by simply setting a Class3 instance variable after Class3 has be created:

```
pClass3.class2View= pClass2View;
```

Does this answer your question or am I missing something?